# Android get view coordinates if moved

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, android

I have an ImageView aligned in the center of RelativeLayout, and I want it to transition to alignedParentTop. How to get deltaY necessary to set up TranslateAnimation?

EDIT:
Since I've been asked to showcase what I've already done, here's the code I'm using:

```
  private Animation getTranslateAnimation(final View v) {
    final float yDelta = getScreenHeight() - (2 * v.getHeight());

    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, yDelta);

    translateAnimation.setDuration(Initial.DURATION_MILLIS);
    translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    return translateAnimation;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I have EditText that I show after this animation, and it should be positioned just below the ImageView. I've set AnimationListener that makes it visible onAnimationEnd, but it positions it below the original position, not the new one. Is there some easy way around or should I switch to PropertyAnimation framework?

Comment: A lot of different approaches to this. Where is the view displayed (activity, fragment, dialog, etc)? Since top left corner is 0,0 basic idea would be to just get X for current view (assuming you want it to stay in that position) and move y to 0. I can show code with more info. Can you post what you've tried in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [Animation Resources Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View), you will see that you can just define the values relative to parent or self. So you could have an xml-resource looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

This will have the effect, that the view is translated from its original position, up to aligning with parent top (because `android:toYDelta="0%p"` - the "p" indicates that it's relative to parent).

If you don't need to really do it programmatically, this should work.